# Ubuntu says FAT16, windows says NTF?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

I created a partition on USB harddisk in windows and it reports to be an NTFS partition.

Yet in ubuntu 9.10 fdisk says it a FAT16 partition. If I mount with -t ntfs I see nothing, but if I mount without it I see all the files.

Can anyone tell me whats going on here?

Windows computer disk management definately says its NTFS, and a quick look at the raw data suggests it is NTFS, as I know the FAT16 very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a partition on USB harddisk
>   in windows and it reports to be an
>   NTFS partition.
>
> Yet in ubuntu 9.10 fdisk says it a
>   FAT16 partition.

That does not really mean anything. fdisk can only read the partition label, which does not necessarily match the partition's file system.

> If I mount with -t
>   ntfs I see nothing, but if I mount
>   without it I see all the files.

Well, then just look at the ouput of `mount`. It will tell you which filesystem Linux used to mount the fs (the "type..." part).

It is probably NTFS, maybe under a different name. E.g. the new in-kernel NTFS driver will show up as "type fuseblk", as it uses [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to implement NTFS.

Comment: Yup -- sounds like the wrong partition type in the partition table to me. Upvoted.

Comment: So it should be safe to use sfdisk to change it to whatever mount says it is? Looks like windows made an FAT16 partition type, but with an NTFS file system. (edit : just checked and it is fuseblk type, so it is NTFS)

Comment: @myforwik: In theory yes. But be very careful editing your partitions; if you make a mistake, you might lose all your data. Anyway, there's no reason to change the partition type. AFAIK it's not used by any software, it's just for display.